# Is there a collision detection algorithm that checks if any outer points are overlapping on an object?

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, game-development

I have been doing some high level reading on collision detection.

I know you can use a bounding volume and check the intersection using objects such as circles and rectangles.

However, for more complex objects, is there a named alogorithm that checks a collision by only comparing the outermost points of an object to see if they are intersecting?

This way you could have the most accuracy of the collision without using any bounding volume.

I would imagine this is less efficient so maybe that's why it's not used as often?

Comment: The [wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) is a good place to start. If nothing else, the article has [lots of additional resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#See_also) listed at the bottom.